# Save textarea with Insert and then after Update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

Is there any way that I can make it so when someone clicks save on a textarea for the first time, it inserts it into the database and then anytime they click that save button after, it updates the row it has just created and doesn't insert a new row every time they update the same textarea?

Guessing this one is any easy thing just really not sure how you would do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `certainTable` WHERE `uid`='".$user_id."'";
$res = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if($res->num_rows > 0){
    // update query
} else {
    // insert query
}
```

Just check if the user has a row in the table, if they do (`$res->num_rows > 0`) update their row, else insert a new row.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
​<form id="new_one">
​<textarea name="text" id="textArea"></textarea>
​<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
​</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

var formData = $('#textArea').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/php/page/',
        data: formData
    }); 
});​​​​​​
```

I was going to do the PHP, but seems like that has already been posted. Hopefully that helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/charliepage88/G6jce/

Comment: Thanks! Combined with the PHP was exactly what I am looking for.